# How I can control the Zoom ability of a chart in winform C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, zooming

I have a chart, in it there is one chartarea with x-axis y-axis.
First of all, I have to set it to zoomable,

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
```

By default, if I select a rectangular area using the mouse, the chart will zoom to the selected area.
But this is quite annoying because it is prone to false operation.
But if I do this:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
```

The Axes won't zoom, even if I call

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(a, b);
```

So, I want the chartarea to be zoomable, but I don't like the mouse selection ability.

I found a method,

```
void chart1_SelectionRangeChanged(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
```

It seems that when I select a new area, this method will be called, 
but it is not meant to be override.
What can I do?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
var ca = chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"];
ca.CursorX.IsUserEnabled = false;
ca.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = false;
```

(and same for CursorY, and replacing "ChartArea1" with the name of your chart area if it's different).

This will disable the mouse selection, so you won't risk accidental zooming anymore.